# UITableview cell scrolling down not smooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm looking for a solution about my custom UITableview cell image.

I'm loading few informations (label + UIimageview) in my custom UITableview cell working perfectly but since iOS 12 it's not smooth while i'm scrolling down (it's lagging the first time I'm scrolling down and then it's smooth while I'm scrolling up, probably related to cache image).

```
RecipeTableCell *cell = (RecipeTableCell *)[self.UITableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[RecipeTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Display recipe in the table cell
Recipe *recipe = nil;

 recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 recupereNomFavoris = [[recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"favoris"];
 recupereImage = [[recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"];
 recupereNom = [[recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
 recupereLien = [[recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"lien"];
 recupereGenre = [[recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"genre"];

    }
}

//Display cells informations
cell.nameLabel.text = recipe.name;
cell.genre.text = recipe.genre;
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.image];
```

I tried to add async solution but it takes more than 1 second to load images.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue =dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.image];// Load from file or Bundle as you want                
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
    });
});
```

All of images size are between 1 and 20kb and i load them locally. I'm using constraints in my IB (weight and width + layout constraints).

I tried to implement SDWEBIMAGE but it only allows you to load URL image.

Any suggestions ? I'm struggling with this problem

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the image causes an error you need to use image lazy loading, 
You can use the following library code to set lazy loading, the benefit of this you can set a place holder image with assign UIimageview to image,

SDWebimage: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: your image path or data, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

AlamofireImage: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

```
imageView.af_setImage(withURL: image path, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderImage"))
```

Comment: you can use with local as well as remote image both

Comment: It seems not supported following that answer : https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/697

Comment: you can use path to the local images

Comment: I can't get the code with objective C format..can you please give me the code snapshot following my first question? thank you

Comment: SDWEBIMAGE is not working with local image : https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/697